# Authorizing Ritekit API calls from Python

Tags: python, oauth

I signed up for a free Ritekit API account in order to retrieve information about trending hashtags.

I created a client id and a client secret on Ritekit webpage.

Examples given by the site (https://ritekit.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/hashtags/hashtag-stats) don't include instruction on how to authenticate:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
}
 request = Request('https://api.ritekit.com/v1/stats/multiple-hashtags? tags=', headers=headers)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

How can one set the authorization to make calls to the api in Python?

Comment: It looks to me lke you can just include client_id as a GET parameter, no oAuth required.. https://ritekit.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/options-for-authorizing-api-calls/using-client-id-directly

Comment: This works, thanks!